# onClick's function trigger when component is mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, ecmascript-6

Here my function in the component

```
myFunc = () => {...}
```

I wrote something like this

```
<MyComponent onClick={this.myFunc()}/>
```

onClick's function gonna trigger when component is mounted.
But if I write like this

```
<MyComponent onClick={this.myFunc}/>
```

or this

```
<MyComponent onClick={() => this.myFunc()}/>
```

It's work fine.

Can someone explain to me why this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you do this:

```
<MyComponent onClick={this.myFunc()}/>
```

It calls the function on mount, and assigns the `onClick` to the *return value* of `this.myFunc`. You need to pass a function reference - either of these:

```
<MyComponent onClick={this.myFunc}/>
<MyComponent onClick={() => this.myFunc()}/>
```

The first one passes the reference to `this.myFunc`, and the second passes a new function which calls `myFunc`. You'd need to use the second one if you wanted to pass arguments to `this.myFunc`.

Comment: Don't ever use the second form, it forces `MyComponent` to re-render any time _any_ of this component's props update, whether they're related or not.

Comment: Patrick, In function based components there’s no difference between a function declared inside of the component body, and an arrow function. Unless the non arrow function usage is a reference to a function declared outside of the component function body in module scope.

Comment: @CooperBuckingham the parent is a class component as evidenced by the form of the method declaration provided by OP (and the use of `this`).

Comment: My point was to address any rules of “never” do this, without qualifiers, as I think they tend to do more harm than good without understanding.

Comment: Sure but in this case there are no qualifiers necessary for the advice I gave. It's bad in all cases, and with function components in particular, _both_ forms are _equally_ bad. You must use the first form and additionally memoize the reference to the function using the `useCallback()` hook, so that irrelevant props changes in the parent component don't force the child component to re-render, due to the callback having a new reference.

Comment: Valid point. I guess most of us just rarely end up memoizing all minor callbacks due to the balance of masking dependency bugs / closures vs simple extra renders of minor components. But I concede the point.